# composition- managing distant view of large objects

Tags: camera

I'd like to simply create a mountain range,and the scene has to be fairly low angled. My test render for the scene is as shown below: [image: test scene]

The mountains are approx 500 meters from the camera, and they need to appear big and in composition they should acquire 50% of the scene(i.e. with the horizon which is the lake in this case). Firstly I based this off of actual distance range in real life because I couldn't come with other ways, so I put the mountains 500m from camera and made them approx. 100ft tall but then they consumed the sky. Then I had to shrink them down. But, as you can see now the problem with the scene is that, the mountains look like small hills that I fairly close by and the horizon a small puddle, whereas I'd like them to appear far from the camera and the horizon should look like a vast ocean.

How do I achieve this? I'll attach the .blend below with the textures packed.

[Here's the link](https://ufile.io/g0cfz)

Comment: The link to the blend file seems to be invalid. When sharing files on this site it's best to use blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com as it offers a permanent storage for the life of the question on Blender Stack Exchange. One question to ask relating to your issue is how high above the water is the viewpoint - this can be very significant to give the impression of distance and scale (eg, 5ft off the surface as for typical human height). Also, adding a light 'mist' (using volumetrics or a mist pass in the compositor can emphasize the distance.

Comment: @RichSedman , the camera angle is parallel to the plane.And the giant cow films can't upload more than 30 mb and my file is 35 mb and that was with compression, otherwise it was 75 mb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main issue here is simply the viewpoint - in your scene the camera is actually about 54m above the surface of the lake; Suzanne is scales at 38m. As we (as humans) are used to viewing the world from about 1.5m above the 'floor', this throws out the perspective, giving the impression of a much smaller scene.

By simply moving the camera to about 2m from the surface of the lake you can get a much better perspective, making the mountains look much more distant :

[image: rendered]

Note that for added effect you could add a mist-pass in the compositor or blur based on distance for more realism.

Comment: how do you measure the height of the objects? I measured it approximately with the grease pencil's measuring tool, did you use edge length info or something?

Comment: @mathmaniage The dimensions of the object's "Bounding box" are available in the Properties panel in the 3D View (the right-hand pop-out panel activated by pressing <kbd>N</kbd>). On the same panel are the objects Location (which shows the location of the object's origin), Rotation, and Scale.

Comment: would you suggest a small focal length, that is what I've used in the scene, about 15mm, do you think I should still decrease it?

Comment: Best thing to donis to experiment and try it until you’re satisfied and happy with the result - it’s your project, after all. One thing I would suggest is perhaps more waves on the water - since the camera is now so close to the surface it looks a bit flat close up - you may also need to reduce the height of the waves also.